# WP7 file upload with httpwebrequest and progress indication

Tags: windows-phone-7, file-upload, httpwebrequest

I am using HttpWebRequest to upload images from a Windows Phone 7 application to a WebDAV Server. The upload is no problem and everything works.
Now I want to add a progressbar for the file upload. 
I am using this code to write the data to the stream:

```
    protected void WriteRequestStream(IAsyncResult result)
    {

        Stream stream = (Stream)result.AsyncState;
        Stream streamResponse = httpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(result);

        byte[] content = new byte[4096];
        long totalBytesRead = 0;
        int bytesRead = 0;
        do
        {
            bytesRead = stream.Read(content, 0, content.Length);
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            streamResponse.Write(content, 0, bytesRead);
            streamResponse.Flush();

            if (progressCallback != null)
            {
                float value = (float)totalBytesRead / stream.Length * 100;
                progressCallback(value);
            }
        } while (bytesRead > 0);
        streamResponse.Close();


        httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(requestCallback), null);
    }
```

It seems the data I write in the streamResponse object is buffered before it is sent to the WebDAV server. Therefrom the progessbar is to fast and at 100% before the upload is finished.

I noticed there is no AllowWriteStreamBuffering property in the HttpWebRequest class. Is there any solution to upload a file with HttpWebRequest in WP7 and displaying the upload progress?

Thank you!

Comment: Check this example http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid0986C80F347B0F0BA1FF23DB6565D152CF62CA52.aspx?s=httpwebrequest#L81

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have checked the example and it seems the server in the example code is modified to handle chunk informations within the URI.
In my case it is not possible to modify the server.
I have now tried to upload the files chunked but this does not work.
I have the feeling it is not possible to upload chunked files with httpWebRequest in Windows Phone 7!? There is no SendChunked Property and I don't kown how to tell the server that I am sending chunked data. 
Setting Transfer-Encoding=chunked in the request header causes a NotSupportedException in the EndGetResponse Method

Comment: The link from @WilliamMelani is DEAD DEAD DEAD, koders.com links like that aren't good link for permanent threads.